# How to express the series of $[\tan^{-1}(x)][\tanh^{-1}(x)]$ as $x^2+\left(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}\right)\frac{x^6}{3}...$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

How to express the series of $[\tan^{-1}(x)][\tanh^{-1}(x)]$ as

$x^2+\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}\right)\dfrac{x^6}{3}+\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}\right)\dfrac{x^{10}}{5}+\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}-\dfrac{1}{11}+\dfrac{1}{13}\right)\dfrac{x^{14}}{7}+...$

I have tried to use Cauchy product or long multiplication, but the result, although of course, are equivalent, is not as elegantly expressed as this expression. This is taken from Ferrar ["A textbook of convergence" page 123](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.197849/page/n125/mode/2up).

For example, for $x^6$, I have $\dfrac{2}{5}-\dfrac{1}{9}$, while for $x^{10}$, I have $\dfrac{2}{9}+\dfrac{1}{25}-\dfrac{2}{21}$. I don't know how to make it pop out the partial Leibnitz series for the coefficients.

Comment: You have a funny term in the coefficient of $x^7$ -- mistakenly, I believe.

Comment: @Allawonder There are no $x^7$ for this series.

Comment: I meant the term in $x^14.$

Comment: Allawonder Fixed.

Comment: I think that should have been $1/9.$ You didn't have to remove it.

Comment: @Allawonder Just fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$f(x)=[\tan^{-1}(x)][\tanh^{-1}(x)]$

$f'(x)=\dfrac{ \tan^{-1}(x)}{1-x^2}+\dfrac{ \tanh^{-1}(x)}{1+x^2} $

If $|x|<1$:

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}  \dfrac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} x^{2n+1}   \right) \left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}   x^{2n}  \right)   +  \left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}  \dfrac{1}{2n+1} x^{2n+1}   \right) \left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^n  x^{2n}  \right)    $

**Edit to show the idea**

$f′(x)=\left(x−\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{x^5}{5}−\dfrac{x^7}{7}+\dfrac{x^9}{9}...\right)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8...)+\left(x+\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{x^5}{5}+\dfrac{x^7}{7}+\dfrac{x^9}{9}...\right)(1−x^2+x^4−x^6+x^8...) $

By using Cauchy product:

$f′(x)=2x+ 2\left(1−\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}\right)x^5+2\left(1 −\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}−\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}\right)x^9+...$

Then we integrate:

$f(x)=x^2+\left(1−\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}\right)\dfrac{x^6}{3} +\left(1 −\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}−\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}\right)\dfrac{x^{10}}{5} +...  $

Comment: Man, this level of manipulation is more advanced than I could do. Could you do it in full steps? Whenever I see a product of 2 infinite series, I cannot manipulate the sigma expressions according to the Cauchy product. I have to write down terms explicitly and multiply them.

Comment: $f'(x)=(x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{x^9}{9}...)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+x^8...)+(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{x^9}{9}...)(1-x^2+x^4-x^6+x^8...)$
$f'(x)=2x + 2(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5})x^5 +2(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9})x^9+...$

Then, $f(x)=x^2 + ...$

Comment: I think you made a mistake in your comment, perhaps because of copying and pasting.

Comment: I think you should copy and paste your comments to your answer.

Comment: The $x^5$, $x^7$, $x^9$ is not right. There are no $2$ factors either.

Comment: How did you come up with this elegant solution?

Comment: Your idea was a good idea, but I did not see how to simplify your expression to obtain the result (now, I know what to do). Then, I searched a differential equation verified by the fonction (bad idea). When I looked at the derivative, I saw the solution I wrote. To expand a function f in power series, it's sometimes a good idea to expand its derivative and then to integrate (for example, $f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)$, if we don't know its expansion).

Comment: Your way of approaching is ingenious. I could never have figured out differentiating the expression, even though I am familiar with integrating and differentiating Taylor series (i.e obtaning the series for $\arctan(x)$. I guess I need to try this way of doing things more often.

Answer (score 2):

Since,
for $|x| < 1$,
$\arctan(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
$,
so
$\arctan(\sqrt{x})
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^nx^{n+\frac12}}{2n+1}
=\sqrt{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^nx^n}{2n+1}
$.

Similarly,
for $|x| < 1$,
$arctanh(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
$,
so
$arctanh(\sqrt{x})
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{n+\frac12}}{2n+1}
=\sqrt{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{2n+1}
$.

Therefore
for $|x| < 1$,
$\arctan(\sqrt{x})arctanh(\sqrt{x})
=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
x^n\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\dfrac1{2(n-k)+1}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\arctan(x)arctanh(x)
&=x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
x^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\dfrac1{2(n-k)+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
x^{2n+2}\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\dfrac1{2(n-k)+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
x^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\dfrac1{2(n-1-k)+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
x^{2n}c_n\\
\end{array}
$

The coefficients are thus
$c_n
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\dfrac1{2(n-1-k)+1}
$.

According to Wolfy,
the first few terms are
$x^2 + \dfrac{13 x^6}{45} + \dfrac{263 x^{10}}{1575} + 
\dfrac{36979x^{14}}{315315}+O(x^{18})
$.

It looks like
$c_{2n} = 0$
and
$c_{2n+1} \ne 0$.
The first should be
straightforward to prove
by reversing the order of summation.

A similar technique
should prove that
$c_{2n+1} > 0$.

As to a closed form
for the sum,
I don't know.

Comment: Thanks, I will go over your answer carefully. Didn't know such an equality is so complicated. There might be patterns all over the places yet we don't know.